# How to check params in a stream in java?

Tags: java, csv, filter, parameters, java-stream

I have a .csv file like this:

```
17/08/2019;15:00;Norwich;Newcastle;3;1;H;S Attwell;1;3;0;0
```

I have to implement a "process" class to work with the data.
Get a string array with parameters to search for like:

```
List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add("Newcastle");
params.add("H");
```

I have to work with streams to find the params in the string.
I tried this but not works:

```
return params.stream()
 .filter(item -> data.contains(item))
 .count();
```

data is the .csv file read in and parsed.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: By the way, you have a wealth of Java libraries to choose from that handle CSV files for you.

Comment: Actually, [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) use COMMA as delimiter, not the SEMICOLON seen in your sample.

Comment: If you can use a library [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial) is a great option to handle CSV files.

Comment: You have one line of a CSV file and the fields could be a variety of types.  You need to provide a [mre] as asked and include additional details on exactly what you want to do,  Show output for specific input.

Comment: What is `data` that has `contains()` method: a String representing entire file, a collection of strings (each representing a cell), a fancy class?  What is the purpose of counting the matched parameters?  Should not you need a filtered collection of rows which contain the parameters?  Should _all_ parameters be found or _any_ of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be good to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as stated but assuming you want to collect the params that exist in the data.

So, you can try the below code snippet;

```
List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add("Newcastle");
params.add("H");
params.add("E");

        
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("17/08/2019","15:0","Norwich","Newcastle","3","1","H","S Attwell","1","3","0","0");

List<String> existingParamList = params.stream()
    .filter(data::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If it is not the case, pls add an example.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;r

```
List
.of( "Newcastle" , "H" )  
.stream()
.anyMatch( 
    List
    .of( 
        "17/08/2019;15:00;Norwich;Newcastle;3;1;H;S Attwell;1;3;0;0"
        .split( ";" )  // Returns an array of `String` objects.
    )                  // Returns a `List` object.
    :: contains        // Defines a method reference, to be passed as a `Predicate` object in our call to `Stream#anyMatch`.
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ZQ8prZ).

> true

## Details

Parse your input string into pieces, using SEMICOLON as the delimiter.

```
List < String > inputs = List.of( "17/08/2019;15:00;Norwich;Newcastle;3;1;H;S Attwell;1;3;0;0".split( ";" ) ) ;
```

That line above first parses the input string into an array of `String` objects, by calling `String#split`. That array is then passed to `List.of` to instantiate a `List` collection object.

Define your targets.

```
List < String > targets = List.of( "Newcastle" , "H" ) ;
```

Run your comparison. Use `Stream#anyMatch` to stop comparing after one hit.

```
boolean inputsContainAtLeastOneTarget = 
    targets.stream().anyMatch( target -> inputs.contains( target ) ) ;
```

We could shorten that `.anyMatch` call by using a method reference.

```
boolean inputsContainAtLeastOneTarget = 
     targets.stream().anyMatch( inputs :: contains ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qnPf61).

> true